# docker-compose: accessing postgres' shell (psql)

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to access PostgreSQL's shell (`psql`) using `docker-compose`, but I'm having some difficulties... Here's my `docker-compose` file:

```
main:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  links:
    - postgresdb
  environment:
    - DEBUG=true


postgresdb:
  build: utils/sql/
  ports:
    - "5432"
  environment:
    - DEBUG=true
```

I've tried to access `psql` by going through the `main` as well as the `postgresdb` services, by running

`docker-compose run postgresdb psql -h postgresdb -U docker mydatabase`

but all I get is `psql: could not translate host name "postgresdb" to address: Name or service not known`... which I don't understand because I use `postgresdb` as the host in the database configuration file e.g.:

```
DB_ACCESS = {
    'drivername': 'postgres',
    # Name of docker-compose service
    'host': 'postgresdb',
    'port': '5432',
    'username': 'docker',
    'password': '',
    'database': 'mydatabase'
}
```

Comment: have you tried `psql -h 127.0.0.1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to connect the Postgresdb container from itself, but container is not aware about the alias `postgresdb` that you have set up inside your `main` container.

Consider the following example:

```
$ docker run -it --rm ubuntu hostname --fqdn
817450b29b34
```

Now you see that Postgresdb doesn't know how to resolve `postgresdb`. But `postgresdb` should be resolvable from `main` anyway.

You have several opportunities to fix this:

1. Try to set hostname for Postgresdb explicitly (in your `docker-compose.yml`);
2. Access the Postgresdb from `main` container in such way:

   ```
   $ docker exec -it main_container_full_name psql -h postgresdb -U docker mydatabase
   ```

Answer (score 20):

Things have changed a bit since the question was originally asked.

Here's how you can access PostgreSQL's shell (psql) using docker-compose today:

1. Use a docker-compose.yml version '2' config file
2. Use 'depends_on' rather than 'links'  (new to version '2')
3. Break up your containers using  'services'

**docker-compoose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:      
   postgresdb:
     build: utils/sql/
     ports:
       - "5432"
     environment:
       - DEBUG=true
   main:
     build: .
     volumes:
       - .:/code
     depends_on:
       - postgresdb
     environment:
       - DEBUG=true
```

**In your docker engine shell ...**

1. Find the container id (or container name) from the `docker ps` command
2. Use that id to open a shell prompt
3. Switch user to the postgres user account
4. Run psql

See example below:

```
                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/
 _                 _   ____     _            _
| |__   ___   ___ | |_|___ \ __| | ___   ___| | _____ _ __
| '_ \ / _ \ / _ \| __| __) / _` |/ _ \ / __| |/ / _ \ '__|
| |_) | (_) | (_) | |_ / __/ (_| | (_) | (__|   <  __/ |
|_.__/ \___/ \___/ \__|_____\__,_|\___/ \___|_|\_\___|_|
Boot2Docker version 1.11.2, build HEAD : a6645c3 - Wed Jun  1 22:59:51 UTC 2016
Docker version 1.11.2, build b9f10c9
docker@default:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
b563764171e2        poc_web             "bundle exec rails s "   43 minutes ago      Up 43 minutes       0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   poc_web_1
c6e480b0f26a        postgres            "/docker-entrypoint.s"   49 minutes ago      Up 49 minutes       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   poc_db_1
docker@default:~$ docker exec -it c6e480b0f26a sh
# su - postgres
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
$ psql
psql (9.5.3)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

**Notes:**

1. docker-compose up will start services in dependency order
2. If you want to stand up a postgres container using the official
   image, you **docker-compose.yml** might look more like the following:

   ```
   version: '2'
   services:      
     db:
       image: postgres
       ports:
         - "5432:5432"
   . . .
   ```

**References**

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Comment: A year on and things are even better: $ docker-compose exec -u postgres postgres psql

Answer (score 14):

Let's start with a minimal `docker-compose.yml` file for reference:

```
version: "3"

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.5
```

You bring your services up with `docker-compose up`.

Let's assume you have a database you want to connect to called `test`.

**Answer:** `docker-compose run --rm postgres psql -h YOUR_SERVICE -U YOUR_USER -d YOUR_DATABASE`

The `--rm` option removes the container after exit, so you don't create unnecessary duplicate containers just for accessing the database.

In our example, this would be `docker-compose run --rm postgres psql -h postgres -U postgres -d test`

Alternatively, you could use psql's connection string: `docker compose run --rm postgres psql -d postgres://YOUR_USER@YOUR_SERVICE/YOUR_DATABASE`

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me:

in **docker-compose.yaml**

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres
```

then, after running `docker-compose up`

I can run

```
sudo docker exec -it -u postgres db psql
postgres=#
```

to get the shell

**Notes:**

1. I'm using docker-compose version 3
2. I've given the psql container a name (*db*). Which allowed me to  avoid running `docker ps` to get the container_id
3. the `-u postgres` allows me to access the container as the *postgres* superuser

Answer (score 2):

**2023:**

```
docker-compose up -d <service-name>
docker-compose exec -u postgres <service-name> psql
```

Voilá!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).